# labjs load google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, labjs

Has anyone used LABjs for loading google analytics?

Where do you include it in the chain?

I found this script but wasn't sure whether to include my other scripts before or after

```js
$LAB
.script("js/myscripts.js") //here?
.script(('https:'==document.location.protocol?'https://ssl':'http://www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js')
.wait(function(){
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXX-X");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
.script("js/myscripts.js") //or here?
});
```

Also, has anyone used LABjs with [getclicky](http://getclicky.com/)? Did you do something similar to the above load chain for google-analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested option is to make another loading chain for google analytics.
Load google analytics script in one chain and your code in the other.

Quote from a gist showing [how to load GA with LabJs](https://gist.github.com/713779) by Kyle.

> I recommend loading google analytics with an entirely separate chain.
>   It's neither dependent on, nor a depdency of, any other code in your
>   page. So load the rest of the code in your page in one chain, and use
>   a separate chain for google analytics.

I have not used getclicky but I would assume the above answer covers that as well.